# Renew iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

A few years ago I wrote an iPad app that was to run on only a few of the client's iPads. They're currently having issues with the app exiting upon being opened. It turns out this is due to the dev provisioning profile associated with the app being expired.

I tried renewing the provisioning profile but am unable to access the Provisioning Portal because my dev account needs to be renewed. Renewing my account is not an option right now.

I'm aware that as of Xcode 8 users are able to install apps on physical devices for free. I don't have access to the client's iPads and have been issuing out updates by archiving the .ipa file and using diawi.com for them to install.

How can I just renew my provisioning profile so that my client can successfully open the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  What you need to do is generate a new, valid provisioning profile and run the app again on your client's iPad.  However, I should note that for this type of development, Apple wants you to use ad-hoc distribution through the enterprise developer program.

Also, to be able to generate a new, valid provisioning profile you will need a valid account.

Comment: Shucks, that's unfortunate. I was hoping at the very least that I could have the UDIDs of the iPads emailed to me and create a new provisioning profile without having a valid account. Thanks MSU_Bulldog

Comment: Also, with the free developer accounts, the provisioning profile only lasts for 7 days, so you'd have to re-build the app to the physical devices every week.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your client should have their own developer account that they maintain, preferably an enterprise dev account (enterprise accounts don't require them to manage the specific device UDIDs the app needs to run on).  With that, they could manage their own certs / profiles for the signing of the app.  They could then grant you access as a team member to manage those things and update the app once a year.

Or, even better for them - you could even write them a script / use tools (like fastlane) to re-sign the app themselves so they could self provision.  This takes you out of the loop for ongoing support, since it doesn't seem like you will / have provided ongoing support.  Keeping an internal app running requires continual work (new OS updates, code signing expiration, etc.).

If you built an app for a client, you probably should have known / let them know that iOS doesn't allow unsigned apps to run on devices, and that developer provisioning profiles last at most a year.  You also need to make sure they know you can't just write a native app and expect it to work forever.  At some point (probably now, but they don't know it yet) an iOS update is going to break something you did in the app. The just can't see what is broken yet because your invalid cert is making it so the app can't launch. Given your lack of understanding of iOS code signing, I would assume that you likely did something in your code that was broken in subsequent iOS updates (given that very experienced iOS developers also have things break with new iOS versions are released).

At this point, I would explain them the situation and see if they would be willing to set up their own paid account (only $299 / year for an enterprise account) to get new profiles / certs set up to get the app back up and running.

Comment: I appreciate your extremely wordy copy of my answer.

Comment: Ha.  I just wanted to provide more information about solving his problem, rather than just telling him it wasn't possible.  It was pretty clear that the poster didn't understand code signing on iOS and I'd hate for him to simply sign up for another account, re-build, and be back here again in a year.   Thanks for reading it and glossing over all the extra points of information I tried to impart!

Comment: Thanks wottle for that detailed response. This was a project I started a few years ago as an undergrad student haha. Live and learn

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of projects that were started that way.  If the client really wants to continue using the app, I would put the burden on them and have them create / pay for a developer account.

Comment: Wottle: I can do that, but was also pondering rewriting the app and releasing it on the App Store for the client under my own developer account. Any thoughts on why I shouldn't do this? (From a provisioning profile perspective)

Comment: You can do that. The challenges would that you would now have to go through the App Store review process, and Apple may reject your app and require you to make changes and resubmit. Also, anyone could then install it from the App Store. Depending on the nature of your app, that could be a problem. The advantage is that the app would not expire. Apple has said they will start removing really old apps from the App Store, so it may not last forever.

Comment: One other option is the business (B2B) App Store. There's a good summary of your options here: http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/